# Correct way to include files in Julia-Lang such that updates are considered

Tags: julia

I admit being new to Julia. However, looking through various documentations I could not find an appropriate answer to my (probably very easy) question.

**What I know from Matlab**

Consider two files in a folder `src/` called `main.m` and `anotherfunc.m`

```
function main
 anotherfunc(0)
end
```

and

```
function anotherfunc(x)
 disp(sin(x))
end
```

I would run `main`in the command window and see the desired result (`=0`). Now, maybe I change my mind and prefer

```
function otherfunc(x)
 disp(cos(x))
end
```

I run `main` again and see `1`.

**What I don't know about Julia**
How to do the exact same thing.
I tried out two approaches that I assumed to be working.

*1)*

The files are `anotherfunc.jl`:

```
function anotherfunc(x)
 print(sin(x))
end
```

and (in the same directory) `main.jl`:

```
function main()
 anotherfunc(0)
end
```

Now I start `julia` in the terminal and write

```
julia> include("anotherfunc.jl")
anotherfunc (generic function with 1 method)

julia> include("main.jl")
main (generic function with 1 method)

julia> main()
0.0
```

Good. Now I change `sin` to `cos` and get

```
julia> main()
0.0
```

This does not suprise me, I know I need another `include`, i.e.

```
julia> include("anotherfunc.jl")
anotherfunc (generic function with 1 method)

julia> main()
1.0
```

So this works but seems pretty prone to errors, I will forget the include in the future.

*2)*
I thought I would be clever and write

```
  function main
     include("anotherfunc.jl")
     anotherfunc(0)
    end
```

But closing `julia`and starting it again gives

```
julia> main()
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching anotherfunc(::Int64)
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 21834, while current world is 21835.
Closest candidates are:
  anotherfunc(::Any) at /some/path/anotherfunc.jl:2 (method too new to be called from this world context.)
Stacktrace:
 [1] main() at /some/path/main.jl:4
```

This is apparently wrong.

***Summarizing: I do not know about the best procedure to handle code that is split over multiple files and changes in a development process.***

Comment: FYI, [Revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is I believe using [`Modules`](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) instead of `include` and the package [`Revise`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/modules/).

Install `Revise.jl` by calling `Pkg.add("Revise")

We have the following `Module` in `MyModule.jl` in your working directory or some other directory.

```
module MyModule

export anotherfunc

function anotherfunc(x)
    display(sin(x))
end

end
```

First, make sure that the directory that the modules are stored is in your `LOAD_PATH`. Julia's working directory is not added to `LOAD_PATH` by default so if you put your module in your working directory then call `push!(LOAD_PATH, pwd())` otherwise call `push!(LOAD_PATH, "/path/to/your/module")`. You can add this code to your `.juliarc` file in order not to call this for each `julia` instance that you run.

Now we have the following main file.

```
using Revise # must come before your module is loaded.
using MyModule

anotherfunc(0)
```

Now change your file `MyModule.jl` so that `anotherfunc` uses `cos` instead of `sin` and see the results.

I suggest you that you read https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/modules/ and https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl

Comment: Thank you for that helpful answer! What would I do, if `anotherfunc` is rather long and I do not want to put the code in `MyModule` itself? Maybe I want to put `anotherfunc2` or `anotherfunc3` in there too, then it would get messy, wouldn't it? Or could I then just put `include("...")` inside the module?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Revise will detect the change even when you change the file included in your module. You will see a warning when a change in your module (or the file included in your module) is detected.